# Is it possible to subtract the returns of two functions?

Tags: python, json, function

Here's the api's wiki: https://github.com/ppy/osu-api/wiki

So I'm building this program to compare ranks, so I grab the usernames and their ranks, and now I'm stuck on how I store the information and the subtract the two from each other to give the difference!

Sorry I have only been coding for about 2-4 weeks, and I'm sure it's something super simple and my code is probably super disgusting.

Code I currently have:

```
def player1():
    payload = {'k': 'myapi', 'u': input()}
    r = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user', params=payload)

    player = r.json()[0]
    return (player["pp_country_rank"])
player = player1()
print(player)

print('Enter a second Username')

def player2():
    payload = {'k': 'myapi', 'u': input()}
    r = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user', params=payload)

    player = r.json()[0]
    return (player["pp_country_rank"])
player = player2()
print(player)
```

Comment: you assigned both players' country ranks to the same variable name `player`

Comment: When you store it to same variable, you replace the first value. Save the return value to different variables and subtract one from the other.

Comment: ...Why do you have two functions that are exactly identical except for their names?

Comment: ...*"Enter a second Username"*, but you don't read from user.

Comment: Okay, I am changing the variables now. Like I said I am new to coding, and I had thought that the two functions would make it easier as far as getting the user and the rank and then just subtracting the two, but I could I could do it all in the same function instead of creating two separate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a function that you call and return the result you can save it to a new variable for later use:

```
newVar = function()
```

This means that later in your code you can use it for something else. Also when you create a function you can define variables for use within the function that can be passed when you call it. For your example you probably want to pass the "username" variable rather than doing the input in the payload.

```
def myFunc(username):
    print(username)
myFunc(random_user)
```

Since I don't have access to your API I created a modified example with comments below that should be doing things in a similar manner to the return you are getting. If you post an example JSON form the API Server then it would be easier to have a working example.

```
# Temp DB Dictionary for showing how things work
users = {
    "user1": [
        {
            "pp_country_rank": 100,
            "other_data": "random"
        }
    ],
    "user2": [
        {
            "pp_country_rank": 95,
            "other_data": "more-random"
        }
    ],
}

# Defining the function. This can be used over and over.
# In this case there will be a variable created in the
# function called "username". If this isn't passed to the
# function when you call it then it will be set to user1.
# If you do set it, whatever you set it to when you call
# the function will overwrite the default.
def getRank(username="user1"):
    # payload = {'k': 'myapi', 'u': username}
    # r = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user', params=payload)
    # Since we created the username variable I can past
    # it to whatever I am calling.
    r = users[username]
    #player = r.json()[0]
    player = r[0]
    # The return here returns the result that gets stored in
    # the variable.
    return (player["pp_country_rank"])

print("Enter first username")
# We are calling the input before passing the result to the
# function
user1 = input()
# We are creating a new variable that will store the result of
# the function getRank(). We pass the stored input of user1 to
# the functuon. In the function that data will be available as
# the variable "username"
user1_rank = getRank(user1)
# There are different ways of formatting and using variables in
# the print. This is one way and where the %s is it will be 
# replaced in order with the variables at the end.
print("%s rank is %s" % (user1, user1_rank))
# We get the second username again storing the input in user2
print('Enter a second Username')
user2 = input()
# We call the same function getRank() but this time we pass the
# data from user2 instead of user1.
user2_rank = getRank(user2)
print("%s rank is %s" % (user2, user2_rank))

# Here we are doing the diff between the two ranks. If you do not
# use abs() then you would have to figure out which rank was bigger
# before doing the substraction to avoid a negative number. This 
# way you will also have a positive diff.
rankDiff = abs(user1_rank - user2_rank)
print("The difference in ranks is %s" % rankDiff)
```

Comment: Forgot to add quotes around user1 in the function definition should be def getRank(username="user1"):

Comment: Awesome, thanks for breaking it all down for me. I'm going to re-write the code to make it look better, and implement the new things I have learned, and you also fixed the little "bug" I would have with the negative number! Really appreciate the help, and the breakdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from Aldric, and Austin realized the mistake I had made... beginner stuff.

```
def player1():
    payload = {'k': '306369747588b5614d76e123cee49dde8f439f7b', 'u': input()}
    r = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user', params=payload)

    player_1 = r.json()[0]
    return int(player_1["pp_country_rank"])
player_1 = player1()
print(player_1)

print('Enter a second Username')

def player2():
    payload = {'k': '306369747588b5614d76e123cee49dde8f439f7b', 'u': input()}
    r = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user', params=payload)

    player = r.json()[0]
    return int(player["pp_country_rank"])
player = player2()
print(player)

print ('Your difference in rank is:')
output = (player_1 - player)
print (output)
```

Is what my code looks like now, and I get the difference I have some small bugs like whenever player_1 is way higher than player it returns a negative integer, and cleaning up the code seeing as some of it is pointless from what I got from Austin, whenever I can just have it all in the same function. But at-least I got it semi doing it's purpose! :)